# Making a Gradle project that includes test files

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

Using the Gradle API, I'm trying to make a project that includes example files. The plugin I'm trying to make should make java interfaces in a folder.

```
@Test
public void pluginCreatesFiles() {
    Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().withProjectDir(new File(testDir, "example")).build() //Build project with Example.java
    project.pluginManager.apply 'solar.dimensions.orbit' //Apply the plugin
    assertTrue(new File(project.getRootDir(), "src/main/java/solar/dimensions/api").exists()); //Does the file exist?
}
```

I apply my gradle plugin with the `Example.java` and test to see if the folder that should be created exists. How do I get the `testDir`?

Comment: It's there a question? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you have to setup that directory on your own. The best way in a junit test for this is to use the temporary folder rule:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder myfolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void pluginCreatesFiles() {
    def projectDir = new File(myfolder.newFolder("folder"), "example")
    Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().withProjectDir(projectDir).build() //Build project with Example.java
    project.pluginManager.apply 'solar.dimensions.orbit' //Apply the plugin
    assertTrue(new File(project.getRootDir(), "src/main/java/solar/dimensions/api").exists()); //Does the file exist?
}
```